# http proxy nodemailer node.js

Tags: node.js, proxy, nodemailer

I am working with **node.js** and **nodemailer** on a network that has a **http proxy**.The emails get sent(via nodemailer) when am on another network(one without a http proxy).

Is there a way of making **nodejs** use the **http proxy** whenever it makes sends requests online?Or are there settings in **nodemailer** that can allow me to set up the host and port for the  http proxy?

Comment: E-mails don't get delivered through HTTP ports (80, 443) but through SMTP port (25), so if the proxy is for http only then there is no use of the proxy anyway even if nodemailer could use proxies (which it doesn't). Can you send mail with a desktop client (Outlook, Thunderbird, Mail.app) from this network?

Comment: Yes i can send mail to outlook behind the proxy network. Even i can also send mail using simple java mail api, but i cant send email using nodemailer. i am getting error like Error type: Error
SMTP log: getaddrinfo
SMTP code: ENOTFOUND